# Microsoft Edge hover bug

Tags: html, css, hover, transition, microsoft-edge

I have a bug in Microsoft Edge. `<div>` during hover has `transform: scale(1.5);` with `transition: transform 1s;`. But when you move cursor to div, wait 1s, move out and then fast move to div, div's scale is broken and transition disappear. Is there any way to fix this behavior? Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ee6rauj/).

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform 1s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this transition problem on Edge use the [`transition-timing-function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function) property, this will fix the problem by affecting the speeding making it slower on the start and the end. You can then set the animation length (in seconds) to make it to the original speed with [`transition-duration`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-duration)

```css
div {
  background-color: green;
  transition: transform 1s;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

EDIT: If you notice carefully there's some kind of a glitch with the width changing on hover, but overall the transition is smooth on Edge

Comment: In IE11 at least, that property causes the transition to go slower when you try to reproduce the OP's issue.

Comment: Yes it does (on all browsers), as I said, it slows the animation's towards the start and end.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying your answer. That explanation wasn't there when I commented.

Comment: Happy to help Vesmy!